# Upgrade to 2.2 XML error

Tags: layout, xml, magento2.2, exception

I am having an issue upgrading to 2.2.2 from 2.1.9. The following occurs when I load the frontend:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 56


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 56

#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(116): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/magent...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)...
```

Looks like the layout xml is not valid but cannot tell where to look. I logged out the xml, but there is tons and dont know where this might be. I looked for where this exception is thrown, however could not find this message anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One of your xml files have some invalid parameter called 'block' check all your theme and extensions xml files for word `block=` or `<block` or something similar 
You should be able to find it quickly and resolve you issue.

Comment: I have been doing searches on my theme and code base but nothing sticks out.

Comment: It is definitely an xml issue. You can try to load a default luma theme instead of your custom theme (change it via database or admin if it loads). - if error keeps poping up - problem in one of your extensions. If problem disappears - your theme has an error.
I hope this will help you. Other way to solve this - go to validation function and check a xml that is throwing an error - this would give you an exact xml where this error exists - by that you will be able to find it. Search through whole project.